# How to create custom pin Start Button to my app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to create my custom pin Start Button to win phone 7.

For example in windows phone 7 i have the button of Marketplace pinned. When i receive update the pin button shows the number of updates i received.
Another example is the calendar, when i create some appointment, these appears in pin button.

I want create something similar. I want a big pin button with some information. Any direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this will probably depend on whether you are targeting Mango or not.

If you are targeting v 7, you will need to look into Notifications.  [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402545%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) will give you some good information as a starting point.

In Mango (7.1) you can accomplish a lot more manipulation of tiles from inside your app.  [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202979%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) is a great start point for that.

Please note, however, that your user will need to have the application tile pinned in order to get the behaviour you are describing.

Comment: I know that is possible but how?! I only want one solution in v7 or Mango (7.1). Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the links above?